# Markdown numbered lists with Vim

Tags: list, vim, markdown

I am using vim to write Markdown. When I type this:

```
1. test
2. test
```

Vim is annoying and formats it to this:

```
1. test 2. test
```

My `formatoptions` (`tqlna`) do include `n`. The filetype is `markdown`. The formatlistpat is the following:

```
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+\\.\\s\\+\\\|^[-*+]\\s\\+
```

Part of it seems to work because Vim understands that it should not reformat lists beginning with `-`, `*` or `+`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's set by the plugin then it's likely better to ask this on the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues).

Comment: Actually I've tried removing the plug-in and the problem is still the same. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `want` as `formatoptions` seems to fix the problem. I'm not able to explain why, though. I knew `w` prevented the behavior I complained about, but I wasn't happy with this solution because then the auto-formatting of normal paragraphs was a bit funky. `want`, which I'd never tried, seems to take care of everything and makes Vim behave like a normal modern soft-wrapped text editor.

I got the idea from this website: http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/03/vim-textwidth/

"I find fo=want to be useful when working on RST documents or emails. Easy mnemonic, too."

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right then vim is actually not recognizing lines starting with `+` but only `*` and `-`. Unfortunately this is due to vim's internal formatter (the `gq` command uses this formatter). The `a` option in your `formatoptions` tells vim to automatically use the internal formatter as you're typing, and this is what's screwing everything up.

If you take the `n` option off and leave your `formatlistpat` then should wrap appropriately when you reach the end of `textwidth` while typing. However, the second you try to format your file with `gq` it will screw it up again.

It looks like what you need is a `formatprg` that formats markdown files in the way you prefer. Then you can set that and leave the `a` option on for automatic formatting. Until you find one I suggest just removing the `a` from your `formatoptions` and not using `gq` to format your file.

You might also want to match for possible whitespace before the `[-*+]` in your pattern. For example,

```
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+\\.\\s\\+\\\|^\\s*[-*+]\\s\\+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually using another `formatprg` is not a solution in my case since I'd really like Vim to behave like a normal text editor when I use it for Markdown. Which means I don't want to be hitting `gq` all the time, I think this makes things harder than they should be. So I can't accept your answer.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Maybe I didn't explain myself well? `gq` is the problem not the solution. If you set the `formatprg` then you can use the `a` option again to auto format.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't have automatic formatting anymore once you set `formatprg` to something else than the built-in formatter, this is what led me to writing the comment I wrote.